# Use of GetGuiResources

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, handle-leak

Is it a good idea to use `GetGuiResources(GetCurrentProcess(), GR_GDIOBJECTS)` at the start of `WinMain`, and before the last return to detect GDI leaks or, more specifically, objects I forgot to release?
Also I'm currently wondering why the first call in my program returns `4` when there's no window yet.

Comment: see also the related question [*How to get GDI objects associated to a process*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251343/how-to-get-gdi-objects-associated-to-a-process)

Answer (score 2):

In most situations, it's enough to use [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). Keep the window open showing the GDI handles of your process (right-click on the columns, choose "Select Columns" and then check the "GDI Objects" checkbox in the "Process Memory" tab).

While running your application, watch the number of GDI handles - if it increases and never goes back, you know you have a leak.

Answer (score 1):

The code with this [MSDN magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301756.aspx) provided a slick way to troubleshoot GDI handle leaks.  Unfortunately, the source code no longer seems to be available...

Answer (score 0):

While this will tell you if you've leaked any GDI objects, it won't tell you anything about which GDI objects you've leaked. In a non-trivial program, I don't see this helping very much.

If you want to track GDI objects, I believe that there are some Performance Counters that display the number of GDI object handles that are currently allocated in a process. You could watch that over time to get a better idea of where your program is leaking.