# How to find out if the object a handle pointing to is already disposed in C#?

Tags: c#, handle, unmanagedresources

I have been working on the codes to safely and efficiently dispose unmanaged objects in C#. This is a Bitmap object created with an image. I like to track the handle to find out the status of image in memory before and after calling Dispose(). Is there a good way to figure out if a handle still pointing a valid object after Dispose() gets called?

Comment: So its an unmanaged object handle? do you want to track it through code?

Comment: No, do not use an oracle.  It is your code that calls Dispose() so you basically cannot not know that it was disposed.  Use a *bool* variable to keep track.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to track the objects used by your process. If your process closes the handle correctly, then you can see through process explorer that the process no longer holds a handle to the object.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds good. Is this a third part framework. Unfortunately, the company computer won't allow any non-approved or non-authorized installation... Is there any built-in functions?

Comment: This tool is from Microsoft. I am not sure if there is a built-in function to do this. I think under the hood, Process Explorer installs a driver that allows it to do things that cannot be done in user mode.

Comment: Process Explorer inspects kernel HANDLEs.... completely unrelated to the question.

Comment: @BenVoigt Well, yes and no. You are right that it does not display GDI objects in the handles view. However, you can still see the number of GDI objects per process by adding the GDI Objects column to the main view.

Comment: @Eric, [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251343/how-to-get-gdi-objects-associated-to-a-process) seems to be a similar question to yours